# Delphi XE AnsiStrings with escaped combining diacritical marks

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe, diacritics

What is the best way to convert a Delphi XE AnsiString containing escaped combining diacritical marks like "Fu\u0308rst" into a frienly WideString "Fürst"?

I am aware of the fact that this is not always possible for all combinations, but the common Latin blocks should be supported without building silly conversion tables on my own. I guess the solution can be found somewhere in the new Characters unit, but I don't get it.

Comment: As far as I know, that's not any standard string format, so you'll have to decode it yourself. Which part are you having trouble with, decoding the escaped characters, or finding the corresponding combined character?

Comment: Decoding the escaped characters is trivial; finding the corresponding combined character is the problem. But it looks like the WinAPI call NormalizeString as suggested by Roddy pointed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to perform [Unicode Normalization.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) on your string.

I don't know if there's a specific call in Delphi XE RTL to do this, but the WinAPI call [NormalizeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319093%28VS.85%29.aspx) should help you here, with mode NormalizationKC:

> NormalizationKC
>
> Unicode normalization form KC, compatibility composition. Transforms
>   each base plus combining characters to
>   the canonical precomposed equivalent
>   and all compatibility characters to
>   their equivalents. For example, the ligature ﬁ becomes f + i; similarly, A + ¨ + ﬁ + n becomes Ä + f + i + n.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look at the NormalizeString function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete code that solved my problem:

```
function Unescape(const s: AnsiString): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  j: Integer;
  c: Integer;
begin
  // Make result at least large enough. This prevents too many reallocs
  SetLength(Result, Length(s));
  i := 1;
  j := 1;
  while i <= Length(s) do begin
    if s[i] = '\' then begin
      if i < Length(s) then begin
        // escaped backslash?
        if s[i + 1] = '\' then begin
          Result[j] := '\';
          inc(i, 2);
        end
        // convert hex number to WideChar
        else if (s[i + 1] = 'u') and (i + 1 + 4 <= Length(s)) 
                and TryStrToInt('$' + string(Copy(s, i + 2, 4)), c) then begin
          inc(i, 6);
          Result[j] := WideChar(c);
        end else begin
          raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid code at position %d', [i]);
        end;
      end else begin
        raise Exception.Create('Unexpected end of string');
      end;
    end else begin
      Result[j] := WideChar(s[i]);
      inc(i);
    end;
    inc(j);
  end;

  // Trim result in case we reserved too much space
  SetLength(Result, j - 1);
end;

const
  NormalizationC = 1;

function NormalizeString(NormForm: Integer; lpSrcString: LPCWSTR; cwSrcLength: Integer;
 lpDstString: LPWSTR; cwDstLength: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'Normaliz.dll';

function Normalize(const s: string): string;
var
  newLength: integer;
begin
  // in NormalizationC mode the result string won't grow longer than the input string
  SetLength(Result, Length(s));
  newLength := NormalizeString(NormalizationC, PChar(s), Length(s), PChar(Result), Length(Result));
  SetLength(Result, newLength);
end;

function UnescapeAndNormalize(const s: AnsiString): string;
begin
  Result := Normalize(Unescape(s));
end;
```

Thank you all! I am sure that my first experience with StackOverflow won't be my last one :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are they always escaped like this? Always in a number of 4 digits?

How is the \ character itself escaped?

Assuming the \character is escaped by \xxxx where xxxx is the code for the \ character, you can easily loop through the string:

```
function Unescape(s: AnsiString): WideString;
var
  i: Integer;
  j: Integer;
  c: Integer;
begin
  // Make result at least large enough. This prevents too many reallocs
  SetLength(Result, Length(s));
  i := 1; j := 1;
  while i <= Length(s) do
  begin
     // If a '\' is found, typecast the following 4 digit integer to widechar
     if s[i] = '\' then
     begin
       if (s[i+1] <> 'u') or not TryStrToInt(Copy(s, i+2, 4), c) then
         raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid code at position %d', [i]);

       Inc(i, 6);
       Result[j] := WideChar(c);
     end
     else
     begin
       Result[j] := WideChar(s[i]);
       Inc(i);
     end;
     Inc(j);
  end;

  // Trim result in case we reserved too much space
  SetLength(Result, j-1);
end;
```

Use like this

```
  MessageBoxW(0, PWideChar(Unescape('\u0252berhaupt')), nil, MB_OK);
```

This code is tested in Delphi 2007, but should work in XE as well due to the explicit use of Ansistring and Widestring.

[edit] Code is ok. Highlighter fails.

Comment: Yes, except he wants to convert 'u\u0308berhaupt' to 'überhaupt'.

Comment: That's true, I didn't read the question well. This code merely converts the C-like notation to 'real' characters. After this, you should still use NormalizeString to, well, normalize the string. That way you can achieve the desired conversion.

Comment: The "\" character is escaped as "\\", easy to handle. Thank you, combining your parser with NormalizeString should solve the problem.

Comment: Small changes made to the parser in my answer: Don't go beyond the string length with s[i+1], convert the 4 chars as a hex string and unescape the backslash itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, Delphi XE now supports regular expressions. I don't use them that often, though, but it seems a good way to parse the string and then replace all escaped values. Maybe someone has a good example of how to do this in Delphi with regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

GolezTrol, 
you forget '$'

```
if (s[i+1] <> 'u') or not TryStrToInt('$'+Copy(s, i+2, 4), c) then
```

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment on @GolezTrol's answer, not as an answer of its own.