# How to decode escaped Unicode Characters (\u30c1 --> チ)?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe2

I'm scraping websites and need to decode javascript escape sequences to standard unicode strings.  For example, the source file contains the sequence:

```
\u30ca\u30c1\u30e5\u30e9\u30eb\u30ed\u30fc\u30bd\u30f3\u3000\u7bc9\u5730\u6771\u5287\u30d3\u30eb
```

and I want to convert it to the string

```
ナチュラルローソン築地東劇ビ
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to use notation like `\u30c1` in Delphi code? If so, replace `\u` by `#$`.

Comment: What are you looking for? A string literal? And which version of Delphi? Presumably a version that supports Unicode, i.e. 2009 or later.

Comment: I want to get japan character like this (ナチュラルローソン築地東劇ビ) but those character show like (\u30ca\u30c1\u30e5\u30e9\u30eb\u30ed\u30fc\u30bd\u30f3\u3000\u7bc9\u5730\u6771\u5287\u30d3\u30eb), how can I get it with pacal? cause now I wrote code with pascal.

Comment: I want to convert this code '\u30ca\u30c1\u30e5\u30e9\u30eb\u30ed\u30fc\u30bd\u30f3\u300‌​0\u7bc9\u5730\u6771\‌​u5287\u30d3\u30eb' to Japanese character.

Comment: You are repeating yourself. We didn't understand the first time you said this, and it wasn't because we didn't try. It doesn't matter how many times you say the same thing. Please read our comments and address **all** the points raised.

Comment: - I'm looking for japanese character as the result from the code above. Ex. ツ = \u30C4(http://graphemica.com/%E3%83%84)
- I'm using XE2

Comment: Yeah, I am screen scraping.

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because the edit to the question somewhat changed the focus and made my answer invalid. This is why it matters to ask the right question from the start. Please take more time when asking to make it 100% clear what you are asking.

Comment: @J... Nope, I used mine already, then retracted it, so we need another hammer

Comment: I think if you look on meta, the consensus is that once a post is closed for the wrong reason, it is better to leave it that way, rather than reopening and then reclosing.

Comment: I have a parser for these. If no one will post here, I can do in hours (it's simple, but have no time). I'm not aware of any function to do that.

Comment: @Victoria See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714023/327083

Comment: @Victoria, it should closed as a dupe to the above link. Unfortunately we ran out of dupe-hammers on this question. Feel free to vote though.

Comment: @LURD, I don't know what it means, but do what you need :)

Comment: @Victoria, rob helped us with his dupe-hammer. It's fine now.